# How do I make a Panel respond to Tap events but not allow the TextBox to be edited?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have the following code:

```
public class IdentityCell : Panel
{
  public IdentityCell()
  {
    Margin = m_zeroThickness;
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    Width = double.NaN;

    m_labelIcon = new Image();
    {
      m_labelIcon.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
      m_labelIcon.Width = getIconSizeToUseInPixels();
      m_labelIcon.Height = getIconSizeToUseInPixels();
    }
    Children.Add(m_labelIcon);

    m_labelName = new TextBox();
    {
      m_labelName.Margin = m_zeroThickness;
      m_labelName.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
      m_labelName.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

      m_labelName.FontSize = (double)
        Application.Current.Resources["PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge"];

      m_labelName.Padding = m_zeroThickness;
      m_labelName.IsHitTestVisible = false;
      m_labelName.BorderThickness = m_zeroThickness;
      m_labelName.Width = double.NaN;
      m_labelName.Foreground = m_phoneForegroundBrush;
      m_labelName.Background = null;
    }
    Children.Add(m_labelName);

    IsHitTestVisible = true;
    Tap += onTap;
  }

  ...
}
```

When the m_labelIcon is tapped, onTap() is called. But when m_labelName is tapped, onTap() is NOT called. If I set m_labelName.IsHitTestVisible to true, tapping on m_labelName causes the control to enter edit mode and the onscreen keyboard to popup. m_labelName is supposed to just be a static text control without editing support. I've tried using the IsEnabled or IsReadOnly properties, but these alter the appearance.

My TextBox is next to my image. The layout looks like this:

```
---- Panel --------------------
<Image> <       TextBox       >
---- Panel --------------------
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Hi, normally if you set your `TextBox`'s `IsHitTestVisible` to `False`, it will not recieve any events, but I am not sure how you layout your controls so it is a bit hard to say what the problem is. So if your `Image` behind your `TextBox`? What are the sizes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **m_labelName** is supposed to be just a static text control without editing support, try using a **TextBlock** instead.

see [TextBlock Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) on msdn.

Comment: You are completely right. I could have sworn it was the other way around! I keep getting tripped up by the TextBox/TextBlock naming.